# "Overload" a template based on the number of template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I am making a template to help make 2-dimensional arrays (matricies). Right now, it is simply an alias of `std::array`s inside a `std::array`, which I like because it keeps the size as part of the type (this will help with compile time checks later on.

```cpp
template <class T, size_t Rows, size_t Columns>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<T, Columns>, Rows>;
```

I would like to optionally omit `T` and have it default to `double` since the common case will be for doubles.

I realize that the normal method for defaulting a template argument is to put it at the end, however, to match the `std::array` API, I would like to avoid using `template <size_t Rows, size_t Columns, class T = double>`.

I tried the following, hopping the compiler could select by the number of template arguments, but it failed with "conflicting declaration of template".

```cpp
template <class T, size_t Rows, size_t Columns>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<T, Columns>, Rows>;

template <size_t Rows, size_t Columns>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<double, Columns>, Rows>;
```

Perhaps there is a fancier way to do this via another template mechanism?

Comment: I guess you can't do much better that to introduce a distinct type alias like `template<size_t Rows, size_t Columns> using Matrix_d = Matrix<double, Rows, Columns>;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot overload aliases.  You can however overload function templates and you could leverage that fact to make a factory function that will create an instance of the class for you.  The would give you functions like

```
template <class T, size_t Rows, size_t Columns>
auto create_matrix() { return std::array<std::array<T, Columns>, Rows>{}; }

template <size_t Rows, size_t Columns>
auto create_matrix() { return std::array<std::array<double, Columns>, Rows>{}; }
```

and then you use it like

```
auto double_matrix = create_matrix<2, 4>();
auto float_matrix = create_matrix<float, 2, 4>();
```

Comment: This seems to be the best option if I want the template arguments to be in the order `<T, Rows, Columns>` thanks!